# Do i need to synchronize read and write actions to the same SerialPort instance?

Tags: multithreading, serial-port

Here's my scenario: I need to read from and write to the same serial port in multiple threads. Instead of creating one SerialPort in each thread, which would cause 'access denied' error, i use kind of global cache to do the job. For each serial port, i keep only one SerialPort object.

```
private static object locker = new object();
internal static Dictionary<int, SerialPort> SerialPorts = new Dictionary<int, SerialPort>();

private SerialPort GetSerialPort(string port)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (!SerialPorts.ContainsKey(port))
            {
                SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port, baudrate);

                sp.Open();

                SerialPorts[key] = sp;
            }
        }

        return SerialPorts[key];
    }
```

In read and write actions, I call GetSerialPort first to get the SerialPort object. Then the respective ReadByte and Write method is called. Now my question is: without any special handling, is it safe to just have multiple threads calling either ReadByte or Write methods at the same time?

Comment: You are going to need a Mutex if the thread that writes the command also needs to get the response.  That's usually the case.  A pretty significant concurrency hazard of course.

Comment: why do i need the Mutex in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> 'is it safe to just have multiple threads calling either ReadByte or
>   Write methods at the same time?'

Yes, that's fine, as long as only one thread reads, and one thread writes, at any one time.

If you have any protocol on top of the serial byte stream, you may have problems, but this is not clear from your question.

Comment: My scenario is not to have one thread for read and write each, but to have multiple threads doing this. It's just the access to SerialPort variable is synchronized.